# How do I return only the bottom 4 rows or a 10 row table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data source that pulls in the same 10 rows of data for customer. I need to only return the bottom 4 rows of the total 10 rows. They are not in alphabetical order so using the Top function and ordering by Desc hasn't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: please provide sql you have tried (also can you supply the table definition you're trying to query?)

Comment: How are they ordered?

Comment: Was able to get it to function by using SELECT *
From (
SELECT *, row_number() over
         (order by *) as Row
        FROM my_table
Where * = @variable
)ZZ
Where Row > 5

Answer (score 0):

Try the `LIMIT` command like this:

```
SELECT name FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5,10
```

Comment: I don't believe that MySQL has a `row_number` window function (or any window functions, for that matter).